# Find items in multiple list?

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, find

I know the question ready to confusion, so a expliquation may be necessary

I try to find a way to ensure that an object can be found in a list among other
and once find (according to the list) do stuff.

Something like this (I know it's completely incorrect, but i don't know how to explain ;) )

```
public void OnPointerClick(BaseEventData eventData)
{
    FindObject(eventData.selectedObject.name);
}

public void  FindObject(string selectedObject)
    {
        switch (selectedObject)
        {
             case for(int i = 0; i < List1.Count; i++)
                  {
                       if(selectedObject == List1[i].Name)
                       {
                           //Do Stuff
                       }
                   }
                   break;

              case for(int i = 0; i < List3.Count; i++)
                  {
                       if(selectedObject == List3[i].Name)
                       {
                           //Do Stuff
                       }
                   }
                   break;

              case for(int i = 0; i < List2.Count; i++)
                  {
                       if(selectedObject == List2[i].Name)
                       {
                           //Do Stuff
                       }
                   }
                   break;
```

I'm turning around maybe my approach is  really bad

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (List1.Any(o=>o.Name == selectedObject)
{
    //do...
}
else if (List2.Any(o=>o.Name == selectedObject)
{
    //do...
}
else if (List3.Any(o=>o.Name == selectedObject)
{
    //do...
}
```

Comment: Thanks It looks like the easiest way, I'm going to use this for the moment ;)